# Checking if a remote location exists

Tags: c#

I have a `console` application that generates a text file and user wants me to put it on a location by `FTP`.
In the `App.config` file there will be `key/value` pairs for information about connection to the FTP and also the location that they want me to upload it there.

I am looking for a way to be able to check first and show error to the user if the location they specify in the `App.config` does not exist.

I searched a little bit but the solutions I found were asking about `ASP.NET` and a valid URL and checking the header, this one is FTP.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried/considered just connecting to the FTP server?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen nop, not yet. Also looking for some simple and working code samples for that too :)

Comment: Well, then now that you have considered it, won't that solve your problem? Try to connect, handle the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are also looking for a FTP library, use: http://ftplib.codeplex.com/
and then use its `ftp.DirectoryExists` method.